# How to remove training data from party:::ctree models?

Tags: r, memory-management, classification, decision-tree

I created several ctree models (about 40 to 80) which I want evaluate rather often.

An issue is that the model objects are very big (40 models require more than 2.8G of memory) and it appears to me, that they stored the training data, maybe as modelname@data and modelname@responses, and not just the informations relevant to predict new data.

Most other R learning packages have configurable options whether to include the data in the model object, but I couldn't find any hints in the documentation. I also tried to assign empty ModelEnv objects by

```
modelname@data <- new("ModelEnv")
```

but there was no effect on the size of the respective RData file.

Anyone knows whether ctree really stores the training data and how to remove all data from ctree models that are irrelevant for new predictions so that I can fit many of them in memory?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

---

Thank you for your feedback, that was already very helpful.

I used `dput` and `str` to take a deeper look at the object and found that no training data is included in the model, but there is a `responses` slot, which seems to have the training labels and rownames. Anyways, I noticed that each node has a weight vector for each training sample. After a while of inspecting the code, I ended up googling a bit and found the following comment in the `party` NEWS log:

```
         CHANGES IN party VERSION 0.9-13 (2007-07-23)

o   update `mvt.f'

o   improve the memory footprint of RandomForest objects
    substancially (by removing the weights slots from each node).
```

It turns out, there is a C function in the party package to remove these weights called `R_remove_weights` with the following definition:

```
SEXP R_remove_weights(SEXP subtree, SEXP removestats) {
    C_remove_weights(subtree, LOGICAL(removestats)[0]);
    return(R_NilValue);
}
```

It also works fine:

```
# cc is my model object

sum(unlist(lapply(slotNames(cc), function (x)  object.size(slot(cc, x)))))
# returns: [1] 2521256
save(cc, file="cc_before.RData")

.Call("R_remove_weights", cc@tree, TRUE, PACKAGE="party")
# returns NULL and removes weights and node statistics

sum(unlist(lapply(slotNames(cc), function (x)  object.size(slot(cc, x)))))
# returns: [1] 1521392
save(cc, file="cc_after.RData")
```

As you can see, it reduces the object size substantially, from roughly 2.5MB to 1.5MB.

What is strange, though, is that the corresponding RData files are insanely huge, and there is no impact on them:

```
$ ls -lh cc*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 9.6M Aug 24 15:44 cc_after.RData
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 9.6M Aug 24 15:43 cc_before.RData
```

Unzipping the file shows the 2.5MB object to occupy nearly 100MB of space:

```
$ cp cc_before.RData cc_before.gz
$ gunzip cc_before.gz 
$ ls -lh cc_before*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  98M Aug 24 15:45 cc_before
```

Any ideas, what could cause this?

Comment: If you could post the result of `dput` on a small sample object that would help.  If you use `str` you can see whether there's training data stored in the object.

Comment: Note: I retagged the question and removed the "party" label as it's not well-defined on SO, certainly not restricted to the R package.  I added memory-management as that seems to be the primary motivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem at hand, so I write this answer if anyone might run into the same issue. I'll describe my process, so it might be a bit rambling, so bear with me.

With no clue, I thought about nuking slots and removing weights to get the objects as small as possible and at least save some memory, in case no fix will be found. So I removed `@data` and `@responses` as a start and prediction went still fine without them, yet no effect on the .RData file size.

I the went the other way round and created and empty ctree model, just pluging the tree into it:

```
> library(party)

## create reference predictions for the dataset
> predictions.org <- treeresponse(c1, d)

## save tree object for reference
save(c1, "testSize_c1.RData")
```

Checking the size of the original object:

```
$ ls -lh testSize_c1.RData 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 9.6M 2011-08-25 14:35 testSize_c1.RData
```

Now, let's create an empty CTree and copy the tree only:

```
## extract the tree only 
> c1Tree <- c1@tree

## create empty tree and plug in the extracted one 
> newCTree <- new("BinaryTree")
> newCTree@tree <- c1Tree

## save tree for reference 
save(newCTree, file="testSize_newCTree.RData")
```

This new tree object is now much smaller:

```
$ ls -lh testSize_newCTree.RData 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 108K 2011-08-25 14:35 testSize_newCTree.RData
```

However, it can't be used to predict:

```
## predict with the new tree
> predictions.new <- treeresponse(newCTree, d)
Error in object@cond_distr_response(newdata = newdata, ...) : 
  unused argument(s) (newdata = newdata)
```

We did not set the `@cond_distr_response`, which might cause the error, so copy the original one as well and try to predict again:

```
## extract cond_distr_response from original tree
> cdr <- c1@cond_distr_response
> newCTree@cond_distr_response <- cdr

## save tree for reference 
save(newCTree, file="testSize_newCTree_with_cdr.RData")

## predict with the new tree
> predictions.new <- treeresponse(newCTree, d)

## check correctness
> identical(predictions.org, predictions.new)
[1] TRUE
```

This works perfectly, but now the size of the RData file is back at its original value:

```
$ ls -lh testSize_newCTree_with_cdr.RData 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 9.6M 2011-08-25 14:37 testSize_newCTree_with_cdr.RData
```

Simply printing the slot, shows it to be a function bound to an environment:

```
> c1@cond_distr_response
function (newdata = NULL, mincriterion = 0, ...) 
{
    wh <- RET@get_where(newdata = newdata, mincriterion = mincriterion)
    response <- object@responses
    if (any(response@is_censored)) {
        swh <- sort(unique(wh))
        RET <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(wh))
        resp <- response@variables[[1]]
        for (i in 1:length(swh)) {
            w <- weights * (where == swh[i])
            RET[wh == swh[i]] <- list(mysurvfit(resp, weights = w))
        }
        return(RET)
    }
    RET <- .Call("R_getpredictions", tree, wh, PACKAGE = "party")
    return(RET)
}
<environment: 0x44e8090>
```

So the answer to the initial question appears to be that the methods of the object bind an environment to it, which is then saved with the object in the corresponding RData file. This might also explain why several packages are loaded when the RData file is read.

Thus, to get rid of the environment, we can't copy the methods, but we can't predict without them either. The rather "dirty" solution is to emulate the functionality of the original methods and call the underlying C code directly. After some digging through the source code, this is indeed possible. As the code copied above suggests, we need to call `get_where`, which determines the terminal node of the tree reached by the input. We then need to call `R_getpredictions` to determine the response from that terminal node for each input sample. The tricky part is that we need to get the data in the right input format and thus have to call the data preprocessing included in ctree:

```
## create a character string of the formula which was used to fit the free
## (there might be a more neat way to do this)
> library(stringr)
> org.formula <- str_c(
                   do.call(str_c, as.list(deparse(c1@data@formula$response[[2]]))),
                   "~", 
                   do.call(str_c, as.list(deparse(c1@data@formula$input[[2]]))))

## call the internal ctree preprocessing 
> data.dpp <- party:::ctreedpp(as.formula(org.formula), d)

## create the data object necessary for the ctree C code
> data.ivf <- party:::initVariableFrame.df(data.dpp@menv@get("input"), 
                                           trafo = ptrafo)

## now call the tree traversal routine, note that it only requires the tree
## extracted from the @tree slot, not the whole object
> nodeID <- .Call("R_get_nodeID", c1Tree, data.ivf, 0, PACKAGE = "party")

## now determine the respective responses
> predictions.syn <- .Call("R_getpredictions", c1Tree, nodeID, PACKAGE = "party")

## check correctness
> identical(predictions.org, predictions.syn)
[1] TRUE
```

We now only need to save the extracted tree and the formula string to be able to predict new data:

```
> save(c1Tree, org.formula, file="testSize_extractedObjects.RData")
```

We can further remove the unnecessary weights as described in the updated question above:

```
> .Call("R_remove_weights", c1Tree, TRUE, PACKAGE="party")
> save(c1Tree, org.formula, file="testSize_extractedObjects__removedWeights.RData")
```

Now let's have a look at the file sizes again:

```
$ ls -lh testSize_extractedObjects*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 109K 2011-08-25 15:31 testSize_extractedObjects.RData
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  43K 2011-08-25 15:31 testSize_extractedObjects__removedWeights.RData
```

Finally, instead of (compressed) 9.6M, only 43K are required to use the model. I should now be able to fit as many as I want in my 3G heap space. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is to remove slots.  A word of caution: this could be rather dangerous given how `party` functions work with the object.

Nonetheless, take a look at `slotNames(yourModel)`.  You can also try `object.size(slot(yourModel), slotNameOfInterest)` to examine the size of different slots.  You could easily create a sorted table to be sure of the sizes of objects in each slot.

In any case, the slot for `data` is a `ModelEnvFormula` (I'll call this "MEF") object.  You could create a dummy MEF: `dummyMEF <- ModelEnvFormula(1 ~ 1)` and then assign that to `data`: `slot(yourModel, "data") <- dummyMEF`.

That will nuke that particular slot.  You should take a look to see if there are other slots that are causing headaches in terms of the storage - the `object.size()` function will assist.  I agree that it's nice to be able to omit training data from the model object.